# How do I get array of types associated with a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have the following data coming from my WP Rest API via `https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies`:

```
{
"category": {
    "name": "Categories",
    "slug": "category",
    "description": "",
    "types": [
        "post"
    ],
    "hierarchical": true,
    "rest_base": "categories",
    "_links": {
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies"
            }
        ],
        "wp:items": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
},
"post_tag": {
    "name": "Tags",
    "slug": "post_tag",
    "description": "",
    "types": [
        "post"
    ],
    "hierarchical": false,
    "rest_base": "tags",
    "_links": {
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies"
            }
        ],
        "wp:items": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/tags"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
},
"dog": {
    "name": "Dogs",
    "slug": "dog",
    "description": "",
    "types": [
        "poodle",
        "labrador",
        "beagle",
        "retriever"
    ],
    "hierarchical": false,
    "rest_base": "dog",
    "_links": {
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies"
            }
        ],
        "wp:items": [
            {
                "href": "https://cms.dboxcg.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/dog"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to retrieve the array of dog types in a custom plugin.

```
[
    "poodle",
    "labrador",
    "beagle",
    "retriever"
]
```

How do I access the above array via wordpress hooks? I have tried the following with no luck:

```
get_taxonomy('dog')->types;
$wp_taxonomies['dog']->types;
```

Here is the code I am trying to implement in a custom plugin:

```
$dog_types = get_taxonomy('dog')->object_type;

foreach ($dog_types as $type) {
    add_filter( "manage_{$type}_posts_columns", 'update_dog_type_columns' );
    add_action( "manage_{$type}_posts_custom_column", 'update_dog_type_column', 10, 2 );
}

function update_dog_type_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => $columns['cb'],
        'title' => __( 'Title' ),
        'image' => __( 'Thumbnail' ),
        'date' => __( 'Date' )
    );

    return $columns;
}

function update_dog_type_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'image':
        $vimeo_link = get_field('vimeo_link');
        if ($vimeo_link) {
            $vimeo_logo_url = 'https://imageurl/vimeo_logo.jpg';
            echo '<img src="' . $vimeo_logo_url . '" height="100px" width="100px" />';
        break;
        } else {
            $img_array = get_field('image');
            $img = $img_array['sizes']['thumbnail'];
            echo '<img src="' . $img . '" height="100px" width="100px" />';
            break;
        }
    case 'year':
        echo get_field( 'year', $post_id );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, as I said on your previous question, you can use `get_taxonomy('dog')->object_type`. But if you mean retrieving it from *that JSON response*, then how are you retrieving it? Via PHP, JS?

Comment: Hi! Ideally I would get the array directly on the backend via PHP. I tried to use `get_taxonomy('dog')->object_type` but I am getting the following error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'object_type' of non-object`.

Comment: What hook did you use? Could you please add your code to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added the code above I am trying to get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the correct code (`get_taxonomy('dog')->object_type`) or [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/), but it should only be used *after the taxonomy has been registered*. Otherwise, the function would return a `false` instead of a proper taxonomy [object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_taxonomy/) which contains properties like `object_type` which is an array of post types registered for the taxonomy.

And because taxonomies are normally (or should be) registered during the `init` hook, you can use any hooks that WordPress fires after the `init` hook, e.g. `wp_loaded` or in your case, you'd want to use the `admin_init` which runs on the admin side of the site like the post editing screens:

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    // Make sure the taxonomy exists.
    if ( ! $tax = get_taxonomy( 'dog' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $tax->object_type as $type ) {
        add_filter( "manage_{$type}_posts_columns", 'update_dog_type_columns' );
        add_action( "manage_{$type}_posts_custom_column", 'update_dog_type_column', 10, 2 );
    }
} );
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I was registering the taxonomy via CPT UI and didn't look at the code that plugin used to register the taxonomy. Didn't realize I was trying to access the taxonomy object before it been registered. Thanks once again Sally.

Comment: You're welcome. :)